# How to deserialize a Map of Map with Play

Tags: scala, playframework

When I execute in the REPL, it works (due to implicit `mapWrites` in the scope):

```
scala> Map("a"->1l, "b"->2l)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Long] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2)

scala> Map("c" -> res0, "d" -> res0)
res1:     scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Long]] = Map(c -> Map(a -> 1, b -> 2), d -> Map(a -> 1, b -> 2))

scala> import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json._

scala> Json.toJson(res1)
res2: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"c":{"a":1,"b":2},"d":{"a":1,"b":2}}
```

Why my code still doesn't compile (it's the same type as in the REPL) ?

```
No Json deserializer found for type Map[String,Map[String,Long]]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
```

[edit] I've found a workaround but i don't understand why i need it :

```
implicit def mapWrites = Writes[Map[String,Map[String,Long]]] ( m => Writes.mapWrites(Writes.mapWrites[Long]).writes(m))
```

Answer (score 0):

Play 2.1 JSON API does not provide a serializer for the Type `Map[String, Object]`.

Define `case class` and `Format` for the specific type instead of `Map[String, Object]`:

```
// { "val1" : "xxx", "val2" : ["a", "b", "c"] }
case class Hoge(val1: String, val2: List[String])

implicit val hogeFormat = Json.format[Hoge]
```

If you don't want to create case class.
The following code provides JSON serializer/deserializer for Map[String, Object]:

```
implicit val objectMapFormat = new Format[Map[String, Object]] {

  def writes(map: Map[String, Object]): JsValue =
    Json.obj(
      "val1" -> map("val1").asInstanceOf[String],
      "val2" -> map("val2").asInstanceOf[List[String]]
    )

  def reads(jv: JsValue): JsResult[Map[String, Object]] =
    JsSuccess(Map("val1" -> (jv \ "val1").as[String], "val2" -> (jv \ "val2").as[List[String]]))
}
```

---

Jackson doesn't know how to deserialize the Scala collection class `scala.collection.immutable.Map`, because it doesn't implement any of the Java collection interfaces.

You can either deserialize to a Java collection:

```
val mapData = mapper.readValue(jsonContent, classOf[java.util.Map[String,String]])
```

or add the Scala module to the mapper:

```
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
val mapData = mapper.readValue(jsonContent, classOf[Map[String,String]])
```

or **you can also try like this**

```
import play.api.libs.json._

    val a1=Map("val1"->"a", "val2"->"b")
    Json.toJSon(a1)
```

Because a1 is just `Map[String,String]` that works OK.

But if I have something more complex like where I have `Map[String,Object]`, that doesn't work:

```
 val a = Map("val1" -> "xxx", "val2"-> List("a", "b", "c"))
    Json.toJSon(a1)
    >>> error: No Json deserializer found for type scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Object]
```

I found that I can do something like the following:

```
val a2 = Map("val1" -> Json.toJson("a"), "val2" -> Json.toJson(List("a", "b", "c")))
Json.toJson(a2)
```

And that works.`

Comment: 1. It's not a Map[String,Object] but a Map[String,Map[String,Long]] 2. I don't need Format (only the Writes)